# Why Does FactoryGirl Generate Factories in the 'test' Directory When I'm Using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, generator, factory-bot

When I generate a model using:

```
$ rails g model example
```

Rails generates a factory for the model. Currently it adds the factory to `test/factories` however I need it to add the factory to `spec/factories`.

I'm using RSpec and everything else is generated to `spec/…`.

Comment: That command line puts the factory in spec/factories for me. Wonder what's different? Might help to show your Gemfile.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth Good Spidey sense. I'd put it in the :test group when it should have been in :development, :test. If you put that in an answer I'll mark as correct. Or I can do it.

Comment: I can't write that answer, since in my hands if rspec-rails is only in test `rails g model` doesn't generate a factory at all. You probably have more in your :development group than I do.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, the place where these files end up, is determined by a directive in the file config/application.rb:

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.generators do |g|
    ...

    g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'

    ...
  end

...
```

Comment: Nice, Didn't know you could pass a directory there.